# Irrationality of 0.123456789101112 ... and similar numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Consider four numbers in $(0,1)$:
$n_1$ in base $10$ is formed by listing the decimal digits $1,2,3,4,\ldots$;
$b_1$ in binary is formed by $0$ and $1$ for each
even and odd digit of $n_1$:
$$
n_1 = 0.123456789101112131415161718192021 \ldots
$$
$$
b_1 = 0.101010101101110111011101110110001 \ldots
$$
$n_2$ and $b_2$ are formed similarly, but listing
the primes $2,3,5,7,\ldots$:
$$
n_2 = 0.23571113171923293137414347535961 \ldots
$$
$$
b_2 = 0.01111111111101011111010101111101 \ldots
$$
Which of these numbers is known to be {rational,
irrational, algebraic, transcendental}?
I presume that all four are irrational.

Comment: Irrationality isn't hard, for any of them.  There are natural numbers with arbitrarily long strings of $1's$ or strings of $0's$, for example.  And, similarly, there are primes with such strings (there are infinitely many primes that start with any fixed sequence).

Comment: Well the first looks like Champernowne's constant: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant.  Better than merely transcendental, it is normal.

Comment: @badjohn It's only known to be normal in base 10, and actually the same is known about $n_2$, which is the [Copeland-Erdos constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland–Erdős_constant). Also, normality is not "better than merely transcendental", all algebraic irrationals are expected to be normal.

Comment: @Wojowu I considered mentioning that but it seems more than necessary for a comment.  The "better than" was intended to be light hearted.  Plenty of numbers are expected to be normal but relatively few are proven to be.

Comment: Thanks, badjohn & Wojowu, for identifying the constants as Champernowne and Copeland-Erdõs.

Answer (score 0):

$n_1$ is the Champernowne constant, which is known to be normal. $n_2$ is the Copeland–Erdős constant, which is also known to be normal in base $10$.

Comment: But a normal number can be either algebraic or transcendental (conjecturally). And the same is true for a non-normal number (proved). In fact the poster asked about transcendence, so you answered something else.