# Rainbow numbers: Can mapping digits to different bases produce different varieties of irrationality?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

This is a follow-up to the question,
"[Irrationality of 0.123456789101112 … and similar numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168112/237)."

There I took some decimal number, in one case 
Champernowne's constant,
$$
n_{10} = 0.123456789101112131415161718192021 \ldots \;,
$$
and then mapped each base-$10$ digit to a
binary digit,
$0$ and $1$ for each
even and odd digit of $n$:
$$
n_{2} = 0.101010101101110111011101110110001 \ldots \;,
$$
where $n_{2}$ is to be interpreted as a binary number.
My question is, essentially:

> ***Q***. Can $n_{10}$ be irrational/transcendental but $n_{2}$ rational?
>   Can you provide examples? Do they work for multiple bases $b$, $n_{b}$?

The ideal would be a number which is trascendental in base-$10$,
but when the digits are mapped to base $b$, it becomes rational
for some $b_1$, algebraic for some other $b_2$, maybe normal for some other $b_3$, etc.

You see where I'm going with this.
I want a *rainbow number*: a number that exhibits
{rational, irrational, algebraic, normal, transcendental}
under this digit mapping.
It could serve as an educational tool.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Base is just representation. Why would the way in which we write some number on a piece of paper changes its properties?

Comment: @Brian: Good question! But notice that $n_{10}$ and $n_2$ are rather different numbers. It is not that $n_2$ is the binary of  $n_{10}$. Rather the  $n_{10}$ digits are mapped to even/odd binary.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification! I overlooked the distinction between converting between bases and concatenating the base-converted digits of a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number
$$
n_{10} = 0.2772727222227227777....
$$
is transcendental, but
$$
n_2 = 0.0110101000001001111... = \sqrt{2}-1
$$
is an algebraic irrational and 
$$
n_5 = 0.2222222222222222222... = 2/3
$$
is rational.

You should be able to use the Chinese remainder theorem to encode as many numbers into the base $b$ expansion of a number as $b$ has distinct prime factors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. For $n_2$ to be rational, the binary expansion must eventually have a repeating pattern of digits. Similarly for $n_{10}$. So simply take $n_2$ to be some repeating pattern, say $n_2=0.101010\dots$ (this is equal to $2/3$). Now by your mapping, $n_{10}$ must consist of alternating odd and even digits in such a way that the pattern never repeats. It's enough to come up with odd and even strings that never repeat, e.g.,
$$1,3,5,7,9,1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,9,9,1,1,1,\dots$$
and
$$2,4,6,8,0,2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8,0,0,2,2,2,\dots.$$
So then the number $n_{10}$ would be:
$$n_{10}=0.123456789012123434565678789090121212\dots.$$

Comment: In fact, you could just take $n_{10}$ to be the string of even digits and get the rational number $n_2 = 0$.